# why can't we have static const for Cell identifier in UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview

When we create UITableViewCell, we give static NSString* value for create the Identifier. I understand why we have static value but why it can't be const as well?

static NSString *defaultIndentifier = @"Object Cell Identifier";